# How to get the default loaded tab text in JQuery UI tabs plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, tabs

This is my code to get the tab's text when I click the tab:

```
$('#tab').tabs({
  fx: { opacity:'toggle', duration:300 },

 select: function(event, ui) {

    var text = $(ui.tab).text();
 }
});
```

But how can I get the `default selected tab's text` when it created.E.g: Three tab:

```
Tabs-Menu1 Tabs-Menu2 Tabs-Menu3
```

And the `Tabs-Menus1` was default selected when the tabs was loaded.And I want to get the `Tabs-Menu1` tab's text at the tabs was loaded.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `create` to run a callback function when the tabs are created:

```
create: function(event, ui) {  
    var text = $(ui.tab).text();
 }
```

Comment: not sure why it doesn't work. I'll upvote you and hopefully we'll get someone with more jQuery experience in here.